# How to modify front end code without restarting the server in google app engine (java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am developing a java app in GAE.

Whenever I need to modify a front end or static file (js, css, jsp, etc), i need to restart the server, re-login in my application, etc, and I end up losing 45 seconds for a minimum change.

Is there a way to be able to modify the front end code and see results refreshed without the need of restarting the appengine server?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use JRebel to achieve this hot swap, but it is costly.

There is a hack that I usually use is, instead of edit the original source file, I open the both source file and target file at the same time. First edit the target file, if satisfied, copy/paste to the origin source file.

Note, while using this approach, you need to be aware that if you restart the server but forget to copy/paste the target file, you will lose all the changes.